# Can we get data from sqlite db when app closed in android? If yes pls add example codes

Tags: android

I am trying to get value from my sqlite db and to generate notification.But this working only when my app is in open state . When i close app this won't works.Can any one suggest any method to work app even if app in closed state.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
private boolean isRunning;
private Context context;
private Thread backgroundThread;
String date;
DbHandler db=new DbHandler(this);
ArrayList<String>listdate=new ArrayList<String>();
int ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.context = this;
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
}

private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {


        // Do something here
        List<OrderItemModel> orderdate =  db.geteachdate();

        for (OrderItemModel om : orderdate) {
            listdate.add(om.getOrder_date());
        }
        Log.e("list bg",listdate+"");
        ArrayList<String> resList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (listdate.size()!=0){


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OrderList.class);

            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            //Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
                    .setTicker("Alert")
                    .setContentTitle("Rent out of date")
                    .setContentText("Check date")
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            // Create Notification Manager
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Build Notification with Notification Manager
            notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.isRunning = false;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   /* Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    date=extras.getString("listdate");
    Log.e("date in service",date);*/
    if(!this.isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = true;
        this.backgroundThread.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Try with [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: tried bt it wrks in background and not when app closed

Comment: This is my service class.This is wroking in background too.But not when app is closed

Comment: What have you tried so far? post it. You can use sqlite database in your Service.

Comment: added my service here

Comment: what do you mean App Closed? Why you can't do with service?

Comment: You've to restart the service whenever it is closed. With-in service, implement the logic. Bind the service and start it again if it is killed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use service :)

Pass the context from Service and use it

Comment: tried bt it wrks in background and not when app closed

Comment: Tell me exactly what you want to achieve. So I can give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open you DB connection like below and access to your Database's data:

```
private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
          //
          ...
          //

          DBHelper mDBHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext() /*OR BackgroundService.this*/);
          //retrive your data

         //
         ...
         //  
    }
```

Your Service should run in background. So in your manifest file, you must use from flag `android:stopWithTask="false"` for that.

Comment: <service android:name=".BackgroundService"
            />
This is in manifest.  Not working

Comment: Not checking when app closed

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AjayShrestha I want to retreve data from my sqlite db even after i kill my app

Answer (score 0):

If you want your service to work even on your app is closed then you have to restart your service in your `onDestroy()` method and you have to keep some logic that if your work is done then service should not start again.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    startService(new Intent(this, YourServiceName.class));

}
```

Comment: Still did'nt got answer